# Is it possible to recover data from an azure blob files?

Tags: azure

I have an account on azure and build a cluster on it (Chemalivethermotest). It has a storage account and I just by mistake erase all data on it (I misanderstood something on the online azure interface). Is there a way to recover the datas? I see there are no files anymore but there are still blob. Are they allowing to recover things?

Thanks you very much for your help.

Comment: I would recommend reaching out to Azure Support immediately. They should be able to recover deleted data if contacted within certain time after the files are deleted.

Comment: Agreed with @GauravMantri - there's nothing anyone can do here to help. This is purely a tech support issue. Unfortunately not something for StackOverflow...

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue you will have to take up directly with Azure support, there is no technical answer. Good luck!